# More Information from ICMP & ARP

Tags: arp, monitoring, icmp

I installed [DEKSI Network Administrator Demo](http://www.deksoftware.com/dna/download.html) and when it is *Creating Map*, in **Step 3 of 4. Searching and selecting hosts for placing on the map**, it found *IP address and Mac* perfectly, but it also found *Network adapter's manufacturer, DNS Name, and Host type*.

[image]

Now, I need a method for getting the **Network adapter's manufacturer, DNS Name** and **Host type** from ICMP or ARP.

Comment: That information is not included in ICMP or ARP. ARP only resolves a layer-3 address into a layer-2 address, and ICMP does a variety of things at layer-3. The information which you want is above layer-4, and questions about protocols above layer-4 are explicitly off-topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I need a method for getting Network adapter's manufacturer, DNS
>   Name and Host type from ICMP or ARP.

That is not possible.

ARP (Address Resolution Protocol) will get the layer-2 address (MAC) for a layer-3 address (IPv4). An ARP request will be broadcast to all devices on a layer-2 network. The request asks who has the layer-2 address for this layer-3 address. An ARP reply will be sent by the owner of the layer-3 address. It will say I have that layer-3 address, and this is the layer-2 address. There is no information of the type that you want.

ICMP is a layer-3 protocol, and it will be used for messages at layer-3:

- Echo Request and Echo Reply - Ping
- Destination Unreachable
- Redirect
- Router Advertisement
- Router Solicitation
- Time Exceeded
- Parameter Problem
- Timestamp
- Timestamp Reply

Some of the ICMP messages have sub-information.

You will need to resort to other methods to get the information you are seeking.

Comment: There is no way I can recognize the type of the devices ( Switch, Router, Workstation, ... ) and distinguish them?

Comment: No. You will need to look at other protocols, e.g. SNMP, for things like that. The OUI on the MAC address can tell you the manufacturer of the NIC, but that doesn't necessarily tell you what the device is. For instance, you could have an Intel NIC in all types of equipment. DNS is a protocol above OSI layer-4 (off-topic here), and you need to get the DNS name from a DNS server. The host itself may not be aware of the DNS name.

Answer (score 2):

You could potentially get the manufacturer of the NIC from the ARP table, but you need to take the MAC address from the ARP mapping and do a lookup using a 3rd party source to determine the Organizationally Unique Identifier (the first six hex digits of the MAC).

For DNS name you can do a reverse lookup on the IP address from the ARP table using nslookup or something similar.  This is assuming there is a pointer record for the IP.

I'm not sure what you mean by Host Type.

Comment: Thanks john. **Host type** gave me some information of Device such as *Device is Switch(Hub), Router, Workstation,* etc.